# Angularjs Controller is not a function, got undefined after creating a Factory file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, factory

First I had a file called angular-controller.js where there was my app controller, and calling it in my html ng-controller it worked. Now I decide to make another file, a Factory file, to separate some functions from controller file, but now there are an error: 
`Error: Argument 'LoginController' is not a function, got undefined
    at assertArg (angular.js:1099)
    at assertArgFn (angular.js:1109)
    at angular.js:4978
    at angular.js:4560
    at forEach (angular.js:137)
    at nodeLinkFn (angular.js:4545)
    at compositeLinkFn (angular.js:4191)
    at publicLinkFn (angular.js:4096)
    at angular.js:1660
    at Object.$eval (angular.js:8218)`

This is my angular-controller.js (with my controller):

```js
var app = angular.module("StaffLogin", []);  

app.controller("LoginController", function($scope, $http, restService) {  
    $scope.stafflogins = [];
    $scope.staffLoginForm = {  
        email: "",
        pass: ""
    };
    $scope.tokenStaffForm = {  
        idtokenstaff: -1,    
        tokenstaff: ""
    };  
    $scope.staffForm = {  
        idstaff : -1,    
        staffType: {
            idstaffType: -1,
            type: ""
         },
        name: "",
        surname: "",
        birthDate: "",
        phone: "",
        gender: true,
        working: true,
        staffLogin: {
            idstaffLogin: -1,
            email: "",
            pass: "" 
          }
    };  
    
    $scope.submitCredentials= function() { 
        restService.login();
        console.log($scope.staffLoginForm);
       /* $http({  
            method : 'POST',  
            url : 'http://localhost:8080/FoodDrinkDispener/rest/tokenstaff',
            data : angular.toJson($scope.staffLoginForm), 
            }).then(function successCallback(response) {  
                    if (typeof response.data === 'object'){
                        _logsuccess(response)
                        return response.status;
                     }
                    else 
                        _logerror(response);
                    },function (response) { 
                    console.log($scope.tokenStaffForm);
                        _logerror(response);
                    }
                    );*/
            
                }
        
            
            
    function _SetToken(CurrentToken) {
        sessionStorage.setItem("token", (CurrentToken === null) ? null : JSON.stringify(CurrentToken));
        //console.log(CurrentToken);    
    }   
        
    function _logsuccess(response) {  
        console.log("Loggato correttamente");
        console.log(response.status);
        var CurrentToken = response.data;
        _SetToken(CurrentToken);                                        
    }  
            
    function _logerror(response) {  
        console.log("Login fallito");
        console.log(response.status);
        _SetToken(null);                                      
    } 
       
        

    
    

     console.log(sessionStorage.getItem.toString);
    });
```

This is my factory file called rest-services.js:

```js
//'use strict';

var app = angular.module("StaffLogin", []);  
app.factory("restService", function($scope, $http) {  
    var REST_URL = "http://localhost:8080/FoodDrinkDispener/rest/";
    
    function _GetToken() {
        var token = sessionStorage.getItem("token");
        if (token !== null) 
            return JSON.parse(token);
    }
    
    function _SetToken(CurrentToken) {
        sessionStorage.setItem("token", (CurrentToken === null) ? null : JSON.stringify(CurrentToken));
    }
    
    return {
        login: function(loginform){
            return $http({  
            method : 'POST',  
            url : REST_URL+'tokenstaff',
            data : angular.toJson(loginform), 
            }).then(function successCallback(response) {  
                    if (typeof response.data === 'object'){
                       // _logsuccess(response)
                        console.log("login andato a buon fine");
                        return response.status;
                     }
                    else 
                        console.log("login error");
                    },function (response) { 
                    console.log($scope.tokenStaffForm);
                        console.log("login error");
                    }
                    );
        }    
        
    }
    
    
});
```

And this is my html file where I called the controller "LoginController"

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- saved from url=(0066)https://hackerstribe.com/guide/IT-bootstrap-3.1.1/examples/signin/ -->
<html lang="en"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/puzzle.png" />

    


    
    <title>Login</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="./styles/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="./styles/signin.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy this line! -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../../assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>

  <body ng-app="StaffLogin" ng-controller="LoginController" ng-fa>

    <div class="container">

      <form class="form-signin" role="form" ng-controller="LoginController" ng-submit="submitCredentials()" novalidate>
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Hai bisogno di autenticarti</h2>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required="" autofocus="" id="email" ng-model="staffLoginForm.email"> 
        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required="" id="password" ng-model="staffLoginForm.pass">
        <label class="checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Ricordami
        </label>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
      </form>

    </div> <!-- /container -->


    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
  
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.js"></script> 
    <script src="scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript"></script>
    <script src="scripts/login-controller.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/rest-services.js"></script>

</body></html>
```

I hope that somebody can help me

Comment: You are giving ng-controller 2 times..

Comment: It seems you have not included the `angular-controller.js` file in your `index.html` file ?

Comment: @Chetan I tried to delete one of the calls to the controller but things do not change 
and without the factory it worked

Comment: @DavidR read on the bottom of my html file: there are the inclusion

Comment: Try @ved's code will work i guess..

Comment: Yes, it works well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For factory file rest-services.js,change:

```
var app = angular.module("StaffLogin", []);
```

to

```
`var app = angular.module("StaffLogin");` 
app.factory("restService", function($http) {  
         // code
});
```

2. You can't add $scope as dependency in Factory/services.

Comment: In this way show me another error: 
angular.js:5930 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope <- restService

Comment: My mistake. You can not include $scope in factory

Comment: Welcome @AlfonsoSilvestri

Comment: (without [] and without $scope)

Comment: @AlfonsoSilvestri yes. And $scope is for controllers only. You can also use $scope inside Directives

Comment: ah, it's ok!! I understand now